# How to merge 2 pivot tables (DataFrame objects) in 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

From 2 series objects, which contain dogs colors I try to create 1 DataFrame object where each column is a dogs breed, and each row a color.

I've transformed 2 series objects into data_frame objects and grouped each on color.

```py
poodle = pd.Series(['grey', 'grey', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black'])
shihtzu = pd.Series(['grey', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black'])

poodle = poodle.to_frame()
poodle.columns = ['poodle_color']
poodle = poodle.groupby('poodle_color').poodle_color.count().to_frame()

shihtzu = shihtzu.to_frame()
shihtzu.columns = ['shihtzu_color']
shihtzu = shihtzu.groupby('shihtzu_color').shihtzu_color.count().to_frame()

dogs = pd.merge(
    poodle,
    shihtzu,
    left_on='poodle_color',
    right_on='shihtzu_color', suffixes=['poodle', 'shihtzu'])

print(dogs)
```

Expected result should look like this:

[pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy6WY.png)

Actual output is:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [poodle_color, shihtzu_color]
Index: []

Comment: Use `dogs = pd.merge(
    poodle,
    shihtzu,
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True, suffixes=['poodle', 'shihtzu'])`

Comment: jezrael, thank you very much. I've learnt documentation. left_index and right_index parameters mean that we join on their basis. I will use it.